# Giving money for my boyfriend to come back to California

Tags: money-transfer, california

My boyfriend lives in Pennsylvania, well for a little bit, but for my birthday, all I want is for him to be with me, although he was supposed to come on December, I can't wait any longer. His parents wouldn't lend him enough money for a plane or hotel, I can't access my bank account my dad made me, my mom would give me money if my dad put my mom on the account. I'm only 14, almost 15, I've been asking my dad for more than a year to get into my account, i think the government was on it at one point. Is there any way I can be able to access it? I probably sound stupid for asking this. I know money giving in another country isn't simple.

Comment: This is really difficult to read/follow. Could you re-write it more coherently? I don't follow what "the government" is involved in, nor what money giving in another country has to do with it. California and Pennsylvania are in the same country...

Comment: ***Scam alert!*** Have you actually met this person face-to-face?  If it's an online-only relationship, I would not send any money.  There's a significant chance that this person doesn't actually want to meet you and just wants to take your money.  It's a scam hundreds of years old: "I love you, please send money so we can meet."

Comment: How old is this boy?  This screams scam to me, I would stay as far as possible from this. Has your father said why he won't let you into the money?  I suspect if you explain this situation to him it will scram scam to him also. I know it doesn't seem like it but your father is trying to protect you, as a father that's what we do.

Answer (score 12):

You probably have a [UMTA/UGMA account](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Gifts_to_Minors_Act). While the money in that account belongs to you, as long as you're a minor (which is until the age of 18, in California) - you cannot directly access it. Instead, your parent(s) or guardian(s) or any other trustee manages that account *for you*, with *your best interests* in mind.

While you may want to spend that money or give it away to your boyfriend or whoever else, it is very likely not in your best interest to do that. That is why your dad refuses. He has a *legal* responsibility, which is called *fiduciary duty*, to ensure the money is spent in a way that is *best for you*. If the fiduciary just lets you spend the money away - you could later, when you're no longer a minor, sue that person for the breach of trust.

When you're older and a bit more mature you'll be able to make your own decisions and do whatever you want with that money. But as long as your parents have the responsibility to act in your best interests, it is likely that your boyfriend will stay in Pennsylvania for a while.

Comment: Well said. To be honest I would've have been more blunt but you said it perfectly.

Comment: @NuWin that's the first time on this forum I've been accused of not being blunt enough ;-D But it's a kid, after all. Be nice :)